# Unexpected token 'EdgeInsets'. package:flutter/…/painting/edge_insets.dart:340 class onst EdgeInsets extends EdgeInsetsGeometry

Tags: dart, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

[I am getting the Following Error , Everything was fine past nightt , and i am sure i have not implemeneted a Major Change , but gettting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aMaR.jpg)

Comment: Have you updated flutter SDK?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please add the code as text using the Code Sample option in the editor {}, this will be useful to reproduce the code and many other benefits. Also please provide more details about what you've done and want you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It says `class  onst EdgeInsets ...`. There is a `c` missing in `const`.
That looks more like file corruption more than anything else.

You could possibly suffering from hard-disk or memory failures. If it's consistent, it's probably the storage which has been corrupted.

Alternatively, you have opened the file, from the Pub cache, in your editor, accidentally overwritten a character, and saved it back. If that's possible, you can also fix it back the same way.

I'd check the S.M.A.R.T. information on the drive, just to be sure. How to do that depends on your operating system.